# Document.ready script not working when page called into a tab

Tags: javascript

I have several pages that are called onto an ajax tabbed area. the pages that are called have javascript on them however the document.ready function will not load for each of these pages when loaded onto the tab. Instead I have had to put a button on the pages to load the function manually. Iv tried putting the document.ready function on both the page being called and the pages calling it but it still wont run. Is there any other way i can use rather than having a button? I dont want buttons displaying on my pages that have to be clicked before it looks good =(

Heres the code that calls the the page:

```
onclick="createNewTab('dhtmlgoodies_tabView1','Remote Access','','RemoteAccess.html',true);return false">Remote Access
```

All the javascript files are connected to the main page.

A button is located on the remoteaccess page:

```
input type='button' value='Load.' onclick='loadlightbox()'
```

The loadlightbox function is inside a javascript file that is conected to the main page:

```
loadlightbox = (function() {
    $('#gallery a').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});
});
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of your code?  Also, are you using an javascript frameworks, or is this plain javascript?

Comment: Some of my code is currently on here: http://tonismicrosoftsurface.comlu.com/ i cant however get onto it for some reason to talk you through it. Dont know if its my pc or that site. I cant remember how up to date this one is but you can try it if it works - PS you'l need to open it in firefox it totally changes in any other brower

Comment: @Chris I could email you a zipped version off my pc if you give me your address

Comment: No thanks... lol!  It would help if you edited your answer to just post the portion of your javascript where you're making the AJAX request.  Just copy it from your code and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no document.ready event being fired when you load the content into the page with JavaScript. Most libraries just stick what is returned with innerHTML. Most libraries just rip out the JavaScript code from the responseText and run it through eval().

You probably want to forget the whole document.ready and just stick the code block at the end.

Comment: Are there any potential ramifications with just sticking the code block at the end? Like the same type of reasons we use document.ready instead of just sticking the javascript at the end of normal pages, or is it ok to do in the case where you're appending to the DOM (so the host page has been fully loaded already)?

Comment: You'l have to forgive me im new to all this. Im im trying to do is load pages onto a tab from the main page (all other pages are called into this onto tabs on this page) the pages being called have things like a jquery lightbox or a jquery datatable but for these to work im having to put buttons on these pages to load the code manually. So your saying i just have to move this code to the bottom of the page im calling, withoug the document.ready on it?

Answer (score 0):

The document.ready function won't fire because the page (document) is already loaded. The remote page is loaded as content not as a document.

Since you are using jquery you should take advantage of the [.load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and also you should take a [unobtrusive approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) to attaching the onclick to your link. This allows your JS and code to be separate.

```
//Using Jquery load 
$("#id_of_link").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#dhtmlgoodies_tabView1').load("RemoteAccess.html",
     function(){
          //callback code here
      })
})
```